# Pet Shelter in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, binary-search-tree

The provided code represents an implementation of a Binary Search Tree `(BST)` in `C++`, specifically tailored for a "Pet Shelter program" that has been the focal theme in a data structures class for an extensive period of six months.

This `BST` structure serves as a container for nodes that hold `Pet*` objects, with the utilization of pointers being mandated by the overarching project requirements.

The implemented code encompasses some fundamental methods commonly associated with a `BST`. These methods allow for operations such as inserting, deleting, and searching for pets based on their names within the tree and much more...

**Restrictions:**

- Has to compile in C++ 11
- No templates
- Have to hold `Pet` pointers in the tree
- Sort the Pets by name

I want to know if there is anything I could improve on, OOP, design choices, code documentation, MakeFile (I've been pasting the same one since I started working with classes), and so on. I really want to learn how to do unit tests in a better way, I think these suck but that's the way she wants us to do them. Any help or insights would be appreciated.

The code should compile by running `make` in the terminal, it compiles to `prog` and after that `./prog` to run.

**`ShelterBST.h`**

```
/** DOCUMENTATION:
 * @author Jakob Balkovec
 * @file shelterBST.h -> @headerfile
 * @brief ShelterBST class variables and methods declaration
 */

#ifndef SHELTERBST_H
#define SHELTERBST_H

#include <string>
#include <vector>

class ShelterBST {
  
private:   
  /** @struct Pet, used to store the age and the naem of a pet in a shelter */
  struct Pet {
    std::string name;
    int age;
    Pet(std::string name = "", int age = 0) : name(name), age(age) {} //Constructor
  };
  
  /** @struct TreeNode, used to implement a tree
   * @members: 
   * Pet *pet -> pointer to a Pet object
   * TreeNode *left -> left child
   * TreeNode *right -> right child
   * 
   * @note noth develop in a new subtree if left or right != NULL
   */
  struct TreeNode {
    struct Pet *pet;
    struct TreeNode *left;
    struct TreeNode *right;
  };
  
  /** @note BST base*/
  struct TreeNode *root;
  
  /** @note Methods*/
  struct TreeNode* insert(struct TreeNode* &root, Pet *pet);
  struct TreeNode* search(struct TreeNode* root, std::string name);
  struct TreeNode* findParent(struct TreeNode* root, std::string name);
  struct TreeNode* findPredecessor(struct TreeNode* root, std::string name);
  struct TreeNode* deleteNode(struct TreeNode* root, std::string name);
  struct TreeNode* destroyTree(struct TreeNode* root);

  void searchHelper(struct TreeNode* &node1, struct TreeNode* &node2, std::string name);
  void inOrder(struct TreeNode* root);
  void postOrder(struct TreeNode* root);
  void preOrder(struct TreeNode* root);
  void copyHelper(TreeNode* root);
  
  int numberOfChildren(struct TreeNode* root, std::string name);
  int numberOfNodes(struct TreeNode* root);
  int numberOfInternalNodes(struct TreeNode* root);
  int numberOfNodesAtLevel(struct TreeNode* root, int level);
  int findHeight(struct TreeNode* root);
  
  bool isBalanced(struct TreeNode* root);
  
  void findPredecessorHelper(struct TreeNode* root, std::vector<std::string> &names);
  void preOrderHelper(struct TreeNode* root, std::vector<std::string> &names);
  void postOrderHelper(struct TreeNode* root, std::vector<std::string> &names);

  /** @note Methods END*/

  /** @note tests*/
  bool testSearch();
  bool testSearchB();
  bool testInsert();
  bool testFindParent();
  bool testFindPredecessor();
  bool testDeleteNode();
  bool testDestroyTree();
  bool testNumberOfChildren();
  bool testNumberOfNodes();
  bool testNumberOfInternalNodes();
  bool testHeight();
  bool testBalance();
  bool testNodesAtLevel();
  bool testInOrder();
  bool testPreOrder();
  bool testPostOrder();
  std::vector<bool> runAllTests(std::vector<bool> &testResults);
  /** @note tests END*/
  
public:
  /** @note Methods*/
  ShelterBST(); //constructor
  ~ShelterBST(); //destructor
  ShelterBST(const ShelterBST& other); //copy constructor
  ShelterBST& operator=(const ShelterBST& other);
  
  void inOrderDisplay(); 
  void preOrderDisplay(); 
  void postOrderDisplay(); 
  void insertPet(std::string name, int age);
  void findInorderPredecessor(std::string name);
  void findParent(std::string name);
  void searchPet(std::string name);
  void deleteNode(std::string name);
  void numberOfNodes();
  void numberOfInternalNodes();
  void numberOfNodesAtLevel(int level);
  void findHeight();
  void isBalanced();
  void destroyTree();
  /** @note Methods END*/

  void test();
};
#endif //SHELTER_BST
```

**`ShelterBST.cpp`**

```
/** DOCUMENTATION: 
 * 
 * @author Jakob Balkovec
 * @file ShelterBST.cpp [Source code]
 * @brief This is the source code file for my ShelterBST class.
 *        Defines all the private and public methods
 * @name Assignment 3
 */

#include <queue>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "ShelterBST.h"
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdexcept>

/** DOCUMENTATION: 
 * CONSTRUCTOR: @name ShelterBST::ShelterBST()
 * @brief 
 */
ShelterBST::ShelterBST() {
  root = nullptr; /** @note set root to NULL*/
}

/** DOCUMENTATION: 
 * DESTRUCTOR: @name ShelterBST::~ShelterBST()
 * @brief Handles the memory/ frees the resources allocated by the constructor
 * @call: calls the destroyTree() method to deallocate all the memory
 */
ShelterBST::~ShelterBST() {
  destroyTree(root); //call destroyTree
}

/** DOCUMENTATION:
 * COPYCONSTRUCTOR: @name ShelterBST::ShelterBST(const ShelterBST& other)
 * @brief Copy constructor for the ShelterBST class.
 * @param other The ShelterBST object to be copied.
 */
ShelterBST::ShelterBST(const ShelterBST& other) {
    root = nullptr;
    copyHelper(other.root);
}

/** DOCUMENTATION:
 * OPERATOR: @name ShelterBST& ShelterBST::operator=()
 * @brief Copy assignment operator for the ShelterBST class.
 * @param other The ShelterBST object to be copied.
 * @return The copied ShelterBST object.
 */
ShelterBST& ShelterBST::operator=(const ShelterBST& other) {
    if (this != &other) {
        destroyTree(root);
        root = nullptr;
        copyHelper(other.root);
    }
    return *this;
}

/** DOCUMENTATON:
 * PRIVATE: @name void ShelterBST::copyHelper() 
 * @brief Copies over all the Pets in a tree rooted at root to this tree.
 * @param root Pointer to the root of the tree to be copied
 */
void ShelterBST::copyHelper(TreeNode* root) {
    if (root == nullptr) {
        return;
    }
    insertPet(root->pet->name, root->pet->age);
    copyHelper(root->left);
    copyHelper(root->right);
}

/** DOCUMENTATION: 
 * PRIVATE: @name struct ShelterBST::TreeNode* ShelterBST::insert() 
 * @brief Inserts a new node with a Pet object into the binary search tree.
 * @param root A pointer to the root of the binary search tree.
 * @param pet A pointer to the Pet object to be inserted into the binary search tree.
 * @return A pointer to the root of the binary search tree, after insertion.
 * @invariant This function assumes that the Pet objects in the tree are ordered by name.
 */
struct ShelterBST::TreeNode* ShelterBST::insert(struct TreeNode*& root, Pet *pet) {
  /** @note if tree is empty create a new node*/
  if(root == nullptr) {
    root = new TreeNode;
    root -> pet = pet;
    /** @note L and R are NULL if just creted*/
    root -> right = nullptr;
    root -> left = nullptr;
  }
  
  /** @note go left*/
  else if (pet -> name < root -> pet -> name) {
    root->left = insert(root->left, pet);
  }
  
  /** @note go right*/
  else if (pet -> name > root -> pet -> name) {
    root->right = insert(root->right, pet);
  }
  
  /** @note handle duplicates*/
  /** @bug TEST:*/
  else {
      TreeNode* existingPet = search(root, pet -> name);
      if (existingPet != nullptr) {
        std::cout << "\n[A pet with this name already exists in the BST]\n";
        return root;
    }
  }
  return root;
} 

/** DOCUMENTATION: 
 * PUBLIC: @name ShelterBST::insertPet()
 * @brief Inserts a new pet into the binary search tree
 * @param name Name of the pet to be inserted
 * @param age Age of the pet to be inserted
 * @return void-type
 */
void ShelterBST::insertPet(std::string name, int age) {
  root = insert(root, new Pet(name, age));
  /** @note handle memory... IN THE END*/
}

/** DOCUMENTATION: 
 * PRIVATE: @name struct ShelterBST::TreeNode* ShelterBST::search() 
 * @brief Searches for a node with a Pet object of the given age in the binary search tree.
 * @param root A pointer to the root of the binary search tree.
 * @param name The name of the Pet object to search for in the binary search tree.
 * @return A pointer to the node with the Pet object of the given age, or nullptr if it does not exist in the tree. 
 * @invariant This function assumes that the Pet objects in the tree are ordered by name.
 */
struct ShelterBST::TreeNode* ShelterBST::search(struct TreeNode* root, std::string name) {
  if(root == nullptr || root -> pet -> name == name) {
    return root;
  }
  
  /** @note go left if greater*/
  else if(name < root -> pet -> name) {
    return search(root -> left, name);
  }
  
  /** @note go right if less*/
  else {
    return search(root -> right, name);
  }
  return nullptr;
}

/** DOCUMENTATION: 
 * PRIVATE: @name struct ShelterBST::TreeNode* ShelterBST::findParent()
 * @brief Finds the parent node of a given node in the binary search tree
 * @param root Root node of the tree
 * @param name Name of the node whose parent is to be found
 * @return Pointer to the parent node, or nullptr if no parent is found
 * @note This function is called recursively to search for the parent of the given node
 */
 /** @bug
  * Returns A is the parent of B when inserted in the following order -> B, A, C
 */
struct ShelterBST::TreeNode* ShelterBST::findParent(struct TreeNode* root, std::string name) {
  if(root == nullptr) {
    return nullptr; /** @note no tree*/
  }
  
  if(root -> pet -> name == name) {
    return root; /** @note the first node is the one we're looking for*/
    /** @note return nullptr*/
  }
  
  /** @note left side using a recursive approach*/
  if(name < root -> pet -> name && root -> left != nullptr) {
    if(root -> left -> pet -> name == name) {
      return root; 
    } else {
      return findParent(root -> left, name);
    }

  /** @note right side using a recursive approach*/
  }else if(name > root -> pet -> name && root -> right != nullptr) {
    if(root -> right -> pet -> name == name) {
      return root;
    } else {
      return findParent(root -> right, name);
    }
  }
  return nullptr;
}

/** DOCUMENTATION: 
 * PUBLIC: @name void ShelterBST::searchPet()
 * @brief Searches for a pet with the given name in the binary search tree
 * @param name Name of the pet to search for
 * @return Pointer to the node containing the pet, or nullptr if the pet is not found
 */
void ShelterBST::searchPet(std::string name) {
  TreeNode* found = search(root, name);
  if(found == nullptr) {
    std::cout << "\n\n[[nullptr] was returned -> A Pet with the name " << found -> pet -> name << " is [NOT] in the BST]\n\n";
  } else {
    std::cout << "\n[A Pet with the name \"" << found->pet->name << "\" [IS] in the BST]\n";

  }
}

/** DOCUMENTATION: 
 * PUBLIC: @name void ShelterBST::findParent() 
 * @brief Finds the parent node of a pet with the given name in the binary search tree
 * @param name Name of the pet whose parent node is to be found
 * @return Pointer to the parent node of the pet, or nullptr if the pet is not found or is the root node
 */
void ShelterBST::findParent(std::string name) {
  TreeNode* parent = findParent(root, name);
  if(parent == nullptr) {
    std::cout << "\n[[" << name << "] does not have a parent]\n";
  }
  std::cout << "\n[The Parent of: [" << name << "] is [" << parent -> pet -> name << "]]\n";
}

/** DOCUMENTATION: 
 * PRIVATE: @name void ShelterBST::preOrderHelper()
 * @brief Recursive helper function that psuhes valeus into a vector
 * @param root Pointer to the root node of the current subtree
 * @param names Vector of pet names representing the current subtree in in-order traversal
 * @remark These functions enable testing later on
 */
 void ShelterBST::preOrderHelper(struct TreeNode* root, std::vector<std::string> &names) {
  if(root == nullptr) {
    return;
  } else if(root != nullptr) {
    preOrderHelper(root -> left, names);
    preOrderHelper(root -> right, names);
    names.push_back(root -> pet -> name);
  }
}

/** DOCUMENTATION: 
 * PRIVATE: @name void ShelterBST::postOrderHelper()
 * @brief Recursive helper function that psuhes valeus into a vector
 * @param root Pointer to the root node of the current subtree
 * @param names Vector of pet names representing the current subtree in in-order traversal
 * @remark These functions enable testing later on
 */
void ShelterBST::postOrderHelper(struct TreeNode* root, std::vector<std::string> &names) {
  if(root == nullptr) {
    return;
  } else if(root != nullptr) {
    names.push_back(root -> pet -> name);
    postOrderHelper(root -> left, names);
    postOrderHelper(root -> right, names);
  }
}
/** DOCUMENTATION: 
 * PRIVATE: @name void ShelterBST::findPredecessorHelper()
 * @brief Recursive helper function for finding the predecessor of a pet with the given name in the binary search tree
 * @param root Pointer to the root node of the current subtree
 * @param names Vector of pet names representing the current subtree in in-order traversal
 */
void ShelterBST::findPredecessorHelper(struct TreeNode *root, std::vector<std::string> &names) {
  /** @brief modifiying the inOrder() traversal so it pushes the values into a vector
   *         from there we can find the predecessor as stated in the PDF File
   */
  
  if(root == nullptr) {
    return;
  } else if(root != nullptr) {
    findPredecessorHelper(root -> left, names);
    names.push_back(root -> pet -> name);
    findPredecessorHelper(root -> right, names);
  }
}

/** DOCUMENTATION: 
 * PRIVATE: @name struct ShelterBST::TreeNode* ShelterBST::findPredecessor()
 * @brief Finds the predecessor of a node in the BST
 * @param root The root of the BST
 * @param name The name of the node whose predecessor is to be found
 * @return A pointer to the predecessor node in the BST
 * @invariant This function assumes that the BST contains the node with the given name
 */
struct ShelterBST::TreeNode* ShelterBST::findPredecessor(struct TreeNode* root, std::string name) {
  //traverse in order, push values into a vector, find predecessor
  
  std::vector<std::string> namesInBST; /** @note empty vecotr*/
  findPredecessorHelper(root, namesInBST); /** @note pushback*/
  
  /** @note search for the predecessor*/
  std::string storedName;
  for(long unsigned int i = 0; i < namesInBST.size(); i++) {
    if(namesInBST[0] == name) {
      return nullptr; /** @note first element's predecessor in NULL*/
    }
    else if(namesInBST[i] == name) {
      storedName = namesInBST[i-1]; /** @note segfaulting here [i-1]*/
    }
  }
  TreeNode* preDecessorNode = search(root, storedName);
  
  return preDecessorNode;
}

/** DOCUMENTATION: 
 * PUBLIC: @name void ShelterBST::findInorderPredecessor()
 * @brief Finds the in-order predecessor of the node with the given name.
 * @param name The name of the node whose in-order predecessor is to be found.
 * @return void-type
 */
void ShelterBST::findInorderPredecessor(std::string name) {
  TreeNode* node = findPredecessor(root, name); /** @note change back to name*/
  if(node == nullptr) {
    std::cout << "\n[\"" << name << "\" does [NOT] have a predecessor]\n";
    return;
  } else {
  std::cout << "\n[The Predecessor of [" << name << "] is: [" << node -> pet -> name << "]\n";
  }
}

/** DOCUMENTATION: 
 * PRIVATE: @name int ShelterBST::numberOfChildren()
 * @brief Counts the number of children of a given node with the given name.
 * @param root Pointer to the root node of the BST.
 * @param name Name of the pet whose children are to be counted.
 * @return The number of children of the node with the given name.
 * @note Returns 0 if there is no tree or if the node with the given name is not found.
 */
int ShelterBST::numberOfChildren(struct TreeNode* root, std::string name) {
  if(root == nullptr) {
    return 0; /** @note no tree*/
  }
  TreeNode* node = search(root, name);
  if(node == nullptr) {
    /** @note node not found*/
    return 0;
  }
  int numOfChildren = 0;
  if(node -> left != nullptr) {
    numOfChildren++;
  }
  if(node -> right != nullptr) {
    numOfChildren++;
  }  
  return numOfChildren;
}

/** DOCUMENTATION: 
 * PRIVATE: @name struct ShelterBST::TreeNode* ShelterBST::deleteNode()
 * @brief Deletes a node with the given name from the tree
 * @param root A pointer to the root of the tree.
 * @param name The name of the node to delete.
 * @return A pointer to the root of the updated tree.
 */

/**
 * BUG: Segufaulting if I delete the predecessor before the root
 */
struct ShelterBST::TreeNode* ShelterBST::deleteNode(struct TreeNode* root, std::string name) {

  /** @note find predecessor if it has 2 children*/
  /** @note delete and link grandchild if only one child*/
  /** @note delete if no children*/

  /** @note parent is inacessible -> segafulting here*/

  int const NO_CHILDREN = 0;
  int const ONE_CHILD = 1;
  int const TWO_CHILDREN = 2;

  /** @note tree is empty*/
  if(root == nullptr) {
    return root;
  }

  TreeNode* toBeDeleted = search(root, name);

  if(toBeDeleted == nullptr) {
    return root; /** @note node not found*/
  }

  /** @note no children*/
  if(numberOfChildren(root, name) == NO_CHILDREN) {
    if(toBeDeleted == root) {
      delete toBeDeleted;
      return nullptr; //idk if thats right
    }
    TreeNode* parent = findParent(root, toBeDeleted -> pet -> name);
      if(toBeDeleted == parent -> left) {
        parent -> left = nullptr;
      } else {
        parent -> right = nullptr;
      }
      delete toBeDeleted;
  }

  else if(numberOfChildren(root, name) == ONE_CHILD && !toBeDeleted -> left) { /** @note != nullptr*/
    if(toBeDeleted == root) {
      TreeNode* temp = root -> right;
      delete root;
      return temp;
    }
    TreeNode* parent = findParent(root, toBeDeleted -> pet -> name);
    if(toBeDeleted == parent -> left) {
      parent -> left = toBeDeleted -> right;
    } else {
      parent -> right = toBeDeleted -> right;
    }
    delete toBeDeleted;
  }

  else if(numberOfChildren(root, name) == ONE_CHILD && !toBeDeleted -> right) {
    if(toBeDeleted == root) {
      TreeNode* temp = root -> right;
      delete root;
      return temp;
    }
    TreeNode* parent = findParent(root, toBeDeleted -> pet -> name);
    if(toBeDeleted == parent -> left) {
      parent -> left = toBeDeleted -> left;
    } else {
      parent -> right = toBeDeleted -> left;
    }
    delete toBeDeleted;
  }  

  else if(numberOfChildren(root, name) == TWO_CHILDREN) {
    TreeNode* predecessor = findPredecessor(root, toBeDeleted -> pet -> name);
    while(predecessor -> right != nullptr) {
      predecessor = predecessor -> right;
      toBeDeleted -> pet -> name = predecessor -> pet -> name;
      toBeDeleted -> left = deleteNode(toBeDeleted -> left, predecessor -> pet -> name);
    }
  }
  return root;
}

/** DOCUMENTATION: 
 * PRIVATE: @name struct ShelterBST::TreeNode* ShelterBST::destroyTree()
 * @brief Recursively deletes all nodes in the tree.
 * @return A null pointer.
 * @param root Pointer to the root of the tree.
 * @note This is a private member function.
 */
struct ShelterBST::TreeNode* ShelterBST::destroyTree(struct TreeNode* root) {
  /** @note using recursion to delete the tree*/
  /** @note base case*/
  if(root == nullptr) {
    return nullptr;
    
    /** @note recursive case*/
  } else {
    destroyTree(root -> left);
    destroyTree(root -> right);
    delete root -> pet;
    delete root;
    return nullptr;
  }
  return nullptr;
}

/** DOCUMENTATION:
 * PUBLIC: @name void ShelterBST::deleteNode()
 * @brief Deletes the node with the specified name from the BST
 * @param name The name of the pet in the node to be deleted.
 */
void ShelterBST::deleteNode(std::string name) {
  TreeNode* deleted = deleteNode(root, name);
  if(search(root, deleted -> pet -> name) == nullptr) {
    std::cout << "\nNode with the name: [" << name << "] was deleted]\n";
    } else {
      std::cout << "\n[Soemthing went wrong]\n";
    }
  }

/** DOCUMENTATION: 
 * PUBLIC: @name void ShelterBST::destroyTree()
 * @brief Calls destroy tree to destroy and deallocated the memory used by the BST
 */
void ShelterBST::destroyTree() {
  root = destroyTree(root);
  if(root != nullptr) {
    std::cout << "\n[Something went wrong]\n";;
  }
}

/** DOCUMENTATION: 
 * PRIVATE: @name void ShelterBST::inOrder() 
 * @brief Traverses the binary search tree in-order, printing the name and age of each Pet object.
 * @param root A pointer to the root of the binary search tree.
 * @invariant This function assumes that the Pet objects in the tree are ordered by name.
 */
void ShelterBST::inOrder(struct TreeNode* root) {
  if(root == nullptr) {
    return; /** @note do nothing*/
  }
  /** @note traverse*/
  else if(root != nullptr) {
    /** @note left-sub tree*/
    inOrder(root -> left);
    
    /** @note cout data*/   
    std::cout << "Name: [" << root -> pet -> name << "]   " << "Age: [" << root -> pet -> age << "]" << std::endl;
    
    /** @note right sub-tree*/
    inOrder(root -> right);
  }
}

/** DOCUMENTATION: 
 * PRIVATE: @name void ShelterBST::postOrder()
 * @brief Traverses the binary search tree in post-order, printing the name and age of each Pet object.
 * @param root A pointer to the root of the binary search tree.
 * @invariant This function assumes that the Pet objects in the tree are ordered by name.
 */
void ShelterBST::postOrder(struct TreeNode* root) {
  if(root == nullptr) {
    return; /** @note do nothing*/
  }
  else if(root != nullptr) {
    /** @note left sub-tree*/
    postOrder(root -> left);
    
    /** @note right sub-tree*/
    postOrder(root -> right);
    
    /** @note cout last*/
    std::cout << "Name: [" << root -> pet -> name << "]   " << "Age: [" << root -> pet -> age << "]" << std::endl;
  }
}

/** DOCUMENTATION: 
 * PRIVATE: @name void ShelterBST::preOrder()
 * @brief Traverses the binary search tree in pre-order, printing the name and age of each Pet object.
 * @param root A pointer to the root of the binary search tree.
 * @invariant This function assumes that the Pet objects in the tree are ordered by name.
 */
void ShelterBST::preOrder(struct TreeNode* root) {
  if(root == nullptr) {
    return; /** @note do nothing*/
    
  }else if(root != nullptr){
    /** @note cout first*/
    std::cout << "Name: [" << root -> pet -> name << "]   " << "Age: [" << root -> pet -> age << "]" << std::endl;
    
    /** @note left sub-tree*/
    postOrder(root -> left);
    
    /** @note right sub-tree*/
    postOrder(root -> right);
  }
}

/** DOCUMENTATION: 
 * PUBLIC: @name void ShelterBST::inOrderDisplay() 
 * @brief Displays the contents of the binary search tree using in-order traversal.
 * @call: calls the corresponding private method
 */
void ShelterBST::inOrderDisplay() {
  std::cout << "\n[In-Order Traversal]";
  std::cout << std::endl << std::endl; 
  inOrder(root);
}

/** DOCUMENTATION: 
 * PUBLIC: @name void ShelterBST::preOrderDisplay()
 * @brief Displays the contents of the binary search tree using pre-order traversal.
 * @call: calls the corresponding private method
 */
void ShelterBST::preOrderDisplay() {
  std::cout << "\n[Pre-Order Traversal]";
  std::cout << std::endl << std::endl;  
  preOrder(root);
}

/** DOCUMENTATION: 
 * PUBLIC: @name void ShelterBST::postOrderDisplay()
 * @brief Displays the contents of the binary search tree using post-order traversal.
 * @call: calls the corresponding private method
 */
void ShelterBST::postOrderDisplay() {
  std::cout << "\n[Post-Order Traversal]";
  std::cout << std::endl << std::endl;
  postOrder(root);
}

/** DOCUMENTATION: 
 * PRIVATE: @name int ShelterBST::numberOfNodes()
 * @brief Counts the number of nodes in the binary search tree rooted at the given node
 * @param root A pointer to the root node of the binary search tree
 * @return The number of nodes in the binary search tree rooted at the given node
 * @note This is a private member function
 */
int ShelterBST::numberOfNodes(struct TreeNode* root) {
  int leftSide = 0;
  int rightSide = 0;
  
  if(root == nullptr) {
    return 0; /** @note tree is empty*/
  }
  /** @note right side*/
  rightSide = numberOfNodes(root -> right);
  
  /** @note left side*/
  leftSide = numberOfNodes(root -> left);
  
  return 1 + leftSide + rightSide; /** @note recursive function call*/
}

/** DOCUMENTATION: 
 * PRIVATE: @name int ShelterBST::numberOfInternalNodes()
 * @brief Returns the number of internal nodes in the binary search tree.
 * @param root Pointer to the root node of the tree.
 * @return Integer representing the number of internal nodes in the tree.
 */
int ShelterBST::numberOfInternalNodes(struct TreeNode* root) {
  if(root == nullptr || (root -> left == nullptr && root -> right == nullptr)) {
    /** @note The tree doesn't exist or we reached a leaf node*/
    return 0; 
  }
  /** @note +1 cuz of root*/
  return 1 + numberOfInternalNodes(root -> left) + numberOfInternalNodes(root -> right); 
  /** @note recursive call*/
}

/** DOCUMENTATION: 
 * PRIVATE: @name int ShelterBST::numberOfNodesAtLevel()
 * @brief Counts the number of nodes at a given level in the binary search tree
 * @param root A pointer to the root node of the binary search tree
 * @param level An integer specifying the level at which to count the nodes
 * @return An integer specifying the number of nodes at the given level
 */

/** BUG:
 * Do I worry about parameter checking(level) -> validation
 * Idk if its working
 */
int ShelterBST::numberOfNodesAtLevel(TreeNode* root, int level) {
  if (root == nullptr) {
    return 0;
  } else if (level == 0) {
    return 1;
  } else {
    int count = 0;
    if (root->left && root->right) {
      count += numberOfNodesAtLevel(root->left, level - 1);
      count += numberOfNodesAtLevel(root->right, level - 1);
    } else if(root -> right && root -> left == nullptr) {
      count += numberOfNodesAtLevel(root -> right, level - 1);
    } else if(root -> left && root -> right == nullptr) {
      count += numberOfNodesAtLevel(root -> left, level - 1);
    }
    return count;
  }
}


/** DOCUMENTATION: 
 * PUBLIC: @name void Shelter::BSTnumberOfNodes()
 * @brief handles UI
 * @return void-type
 */
void ShelterBST::numberOfNodes() { 
  /** @note handle UI in main*/
  std::cout << "\n[The total number of nodes in the BST is: [" << numberOfNodes(root) << "]\n";
}

/** DOCUMENTATION: 
 * PUBLIC: @name void Shelter::BSTnumberOfInternalNodes()
 * @brief handles UI
 * @return void-type
 */
void ShelterBST::numberOfInternalNodes() {
  std::cout << "\n[The total number of internal nodes in the BST is: [" << numberOfInternalNodes(root) << "]]\n";
}

/** DOCUMENTATION: 
 * PUBLIC: @name void ShelterBST::numberOfNodesAtLevel() 
 * @brief handles UI
 * @param level initger corrsponding to the level in a binary tree
 * @return void-type
 */
void ShelterBST::numberOfNodesAtLevel(int level) {
  int nodesAtLevel = numberOfNodesAtLevel(root, level);
  std::cout << "\n[The total number of nodes at level [" << level << "] is: [" << nodesAtLevel << "]]\n"; 
}

/** DOCUMENTATION: 
 * PRIVATE: @name int ShelterBST::findHeight()
 * @brief Calculates the height of the binary search tree starting from the given root node.
 * @param root A pointer to the root node of the binary search tree.
 * @return The height of the binary search tree. 
 * @note The height of the binary search tree is defined as the number of edges on the longest 
 * path from the root node to a leaf node in the tree.
 */
int ShelterBST::findHeight(struct TreeNode* root) {
  if (root == nullptr) {
    return 0;
  }
  int leftHeight = findHeight(root->left);
  int rightHeight = findHeight(root->right);
  return 1 + std::max(leftHeight, rightHeight); /** @note std::max() finds the maximum value in-between the two*/
}

/** DOCUMENTATION:
 * PRIVATE: @name bool ShelterBST::isBalanced() 
 * @brief Check if the binary search tree is balanced.
 * @param root The root node of the binary search tree.
 * @return True if the binary search tree is balanced, false otherwise.
 */
bool ShelterBST::isBalanced(struct TreeNode* root) {
  /** @note find the height of each subtree recursively and compare -> call findHeight with subtrees as params
   * can't differ by more than one
   */
  
    if (root == nullptr) {
        return true;
    }
    int leftHeight = findHeight(root->left); /** @note L subtree*/
    int rightHeight = findHeight(root->right); /** @note R subtree*/
    if (abs(leftHeight - rightHeight) > 1) { /** @note using abs because it cant be negative */
        return false;
    }
    return isBalanced(root->left) && isBalanced(root->right); /** @note true if right and left subtree are balanced*/
}

/** DOCUMENTATION: 
 * PUBLIC: @name void ShelterBST::findHeight() 
 * @brief Handles UI
 * @return void-type
 */
void ShelterBST::findHeight() {
  std::cout << "\n[The height of the tree is: [" << findHeight(root) << "]\n"; 
}

/** DOCUMENTATION:
 * PUBLIC: @name void ShelterBST::isBalanced() 
 * @brief Handles UI
 * @return void-type
 */
void ShelterBST::isBalanced() {
  bool balanced = isBalanced(root);
  
  if(balanced) {
    std::cout << "\n[BST is balanced]\n";
  } else {
    std::cout << "\n[BST is [NOT] balanced]\n";
  }
}

/** DOCUMENTATION:
 * PRIVATE: @name bool ShelterBST::testSearch()
 * @brief Tests the search() function by checking if it returns nullptr for non-existent values.
 * @return Returns true if the search() function correctly returns nullptr for non-existent values, false otherwise.
 * @note Test 1A: Tests for non-existent values
 * @post If the value is not found in the BST, search() should return nullptr.
 * @note Assumes that user does not enter spaces for names.
*/
bool ShelterBST::testSearch() { //?1

  /** @note 
   *  - assuming user doesnt enter spaces for names
   *  - might not work idk yet
  */
  TreeNode* root = nullptr;

  TreeNode* node1 = search(root, "12");
  TreeNode* node2 = search(root, "18");
  TreeNode* node3 = search(root, "11");
  TreeNode* node4 = search(root, "4");
  TreeNode* node5 = search(root, "3");

  std::vector<TreeNode*> nodes;
  nodes.push_back(node1);
  nodes.push_back(node2);
  nodes.push_back(node3);
  nodes.push_back(node4);
  nodes.push_back(node5);

  for(auto node : nodes) { //== to for each loop in python (<3)
    if(node != nullptr) {
      std::cout << "\n *** TEST1 [Expected [nullptr] but got something else] *** \n";
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}

/** DOCUMENTATION:
 * PRIVATE: @name bool ShelterBST::testSearchB()
 * @brief Private function to test search() method of ShelterBST class.
 * @return Returns a boolean value indicating whether the test has passed or not.
 */
bool ShelterBST::testSearchB() { //?2
  TreeNode* root = nullptr;

  /** @note insert nodes*/
  root = insert(root, new Pet("D", 3));
  root = insert(root, new Pet("C", 5));
  root = insert(root, new Pet("R", 2));
  root = insert(root, new Pet("A", 1));

  TreeNode* exists = search(root, "D");
  TreeNode* exists2 = search(root, "R");
  if(exists == nullptr) {
    std::cout << "\n*** TEST2 [Expected [" << root << "] but got [nullptr]] *** \n";
    return false;
  } else if(exists -> pet -> name != "D") {
    std::cout << "\n*** TEST2 [Expected [\"D\"] but got " << exists -> pet -> name <<" *** \n";
  }

  if(exists2 == nullptr) {
    std::cout << "\n*** TEST2 [Expected [" << root << "] but got [nullptr]] *** \n";
    return false;
  } else if(exists2 -> pet -> name != "R") {
    std::cout << "\n*** TEST2 [Expected [\"\"] but got " << exists2 -> pet -> name <<" *** \n";
  }  

  /** @note deallocate*/
  destroyTree(root);
  return true;
}

/** DOCUMENTATION:
 * PRIVATE: @name bool ShelterBST::testInsert() 
 * @brief Private function to test insert() method of ShelterBST class.
 * @return Returns a boolean value indicating whether the test has passed or not.m 
 * @return 
 */
bool ShelterBST::testInsert() { //?3
  TreeNode* root = nullptr;

  /** @note insert nodes*/
  root = insert(root, new Pet("D", 1));
  root = insert(root, new Pet("B", 2));
  root = insert(root, new Pet("A", 3));
  root = insert(root, new Pet("C", 4));
  root = insert(root, new Pet("F", 5));
  root = insert(root, new Pet("G", 6));
  root = insert(root, new Pet("E", 7));
  
  /** @note expected tree
        D
      /   \
     B     F
    / \    / \
   A   C  E   G         
  */

  if(root -> pet -> name != "D") { //A
    std::cout << "\n*** TEST2[A] [Expected [D] but got [" << root -> pet -> name << "]] ***\n";
    return false;
  }

  if(root -> right -> pet -> name != "F") { //B
    std::cout << "\n*** TEST2[B] [Expected [F] but got [" << root -> right -> pet -> name << "]] ***\n";
    return false;
  }

  if(root -> right -> left -> pet -> name != "E") { //C
    std::cout << "\n*** TEST2[C] [Expected [E] but got [" << root -> right -> left -> pet -> name << "]] ***\n";
    return false;
  }

  if(root -> right -> right -> pet -> name != "G") { //D
    std::cout << "\n*** TEST2[D] [Expected [G] but got [" << root -> right -> right -> pet -> name << "]] ***\n";
    return false;
  }

  if(root -> left -> pet -> name != "B") { //E
    std::cout << "\n*** TEST2[E] [Expected [B] but got [" << root -> left -> pet -> name << "]] ***\n";
    return false;
  }

  if(root -> left -> left -> pet -> name != "A") { //F
    std::cout << "\n*** TEST2[F] [Expected [A] but got [" << root -> left -> left -> pet -> name << "]] ***\n";
    return false;
  }

  if(root -> left -> right -> pet -> name != "C") { //G
    std::cout << "\n*** TEST2[G] [Expected [C] but got [" << root -> left -> right -> pet -> name << "]] ***\n";
    return false;
  }

  if(root -> left -> left -> left != nullptr) { //H
    std::cout << "\n*** TEST2[H] [Unexpected node found] ***\n";
    return false;
  }

  if(root -> left -> left -> right != nullptr) { //I
    std::cout << "\n*** TEST2[I] [Unexpected node found] ***\n";
    return false;
  }

  if(root -> left -> right -> left != nullptr) { //J
    std::cout << "\n*** TEST2[J] [Unexpected node found] ***\n";
    return false;
  }

  if(root -> left -> right -> right != nullptr) { //K
    std::cout << "\n*** TEST2[K] [Unexpected node found] ***\n";
    return false;
  }

  if(root -> right -> right -> right != nullptr) { //L
    std::cout << "\n*** TEST2[L] [Unexpected node found] ***\n";
    return false;
  }

  if(root -> right -> right -> left != nullptr) { //M
    std::cout << "\n*** TEST2[M] [Unexpected node found] ***\n";
    return false;
  }

  if(root -> right -> left -> right != nullptr) { //N
    std::cout << "\n*** TEST2[N] [Unexpected node found] ***\n";
    return false;
  }

  if(root -> right -> left -> left != nullptr) { //O
    std::cout << "\n*** TEST2[O] [Unexpected node found] ***\n";
    return false;
  }

  /** @note deallocate*/
  destroyTree(root);
  return true;
}

/** DOCUMENTATION:
 * PRIVATE: @name bool ShelterBST::testFindParent()
 * @brief Private function to test findParent() method of ShelterBST class.
 * @return Returns a boolean value indicating whether the test has passed or not.
 */
bool ShelterBST::testFindParent() { //?4
  TreeNode* root = nullptr;
  Pet* pet1 = new Pet("C", 5);
  root = insert(root, pet1);

  Pet* pet2 = new Pet("B", 3);
  root = insert(root, pet2);

  Pet* pet3 = new Pet("D", 8);
  root = insert(root, pet3);

  Pet* pet4 = new Pet("J", 12);
  root = insert(root, pet4);

  Pet* pet5 = new Pet("A", 17);
  root = insert(root, pet5);

  TreeNode* resultOne = findParent(root, "D");
  if (resultOne->pet->name != "C") {
    return false; /** @test failed*/
    std::cout << "\n*** TEST4 [Expected \"C\" but got \"" << resultOne -> pet -> name << "\"] *** \n"; 
  }

  if (resultOne == nullptr) {
    std::cout << "\n*** TEST4 [Expected " << findParent(root, "C") << " but got [nullptr]] *** \n";
    return false; /** @test failed*/
  }

  destroyTree(root);
  return true; /** @test failed*/
}

/** DOCUMENTATION:
 * PRIVATE: @name bool ShelterBST::testFindPredecessor()
 * @brief Private function to test findPredecessor() method of ShelterBST class.
 * @return Returns a boolean value indicating whether the test has passed or not.
 */
bool ShelterBST::testFindPredecessor() { //?5
  TreeNode* root = nullptr;
  Pet* pet1 = new Pet("C", 5);
  root = insert(root, pet1);

  Pet* pet2 = new Pet("B", 3);
  root = insert(root, pet2);

  Pet* pet3 = new Pet("D", 8);
  root = insert(root, pet3);

  Pet* pet4 = new Pet("J", 12);
  root = insert(root, pet4);

  Pet* pet5 = new Pet("A", 17);
  root = insert(root, pet5);

  std::vector<std::string> names;
  findPredecessorHelper(root, names); 

  if (names.size() != 5 || names[0] != "A" || names[1] != "B" || names[2] != "C" || names[3] != "D" || names[4] != "J") {
    std::cout << "\n*** TEST5 [Expected <\"C\" \"B\" \"D\" \"J\" \"A\"> but got ";
    for(auto name : names) { //for name in names
      std::cout << "\"" << name << "\" ";
    }
    std::cout << ">] ***\n";
    return false; /** @test failed*/
  }

  TreeNode* predecessor = findPredecessor(root, "C");
  
  if(predecessor -> pet -> name != "B") {
    std::cout << "\n*** TEST5 [Expected \"B\" but got \"" << predecessor -> pet -> name << "\"] ***\n"; 
    return false;
  }
  destroyTree(root);
  return true;
}

/** DOCUMENTATION:
 * PRIVATE: @name bool ShelterBST::testDeleteNode()
 * @brief Private function to test deleteNode() method of ShelterBST class.
 * @return Returns a boolean value indicating whether the test has passed or not.
 */
bool ShelterBST::testDeleteNode() { //?6
  TreeNode* root = nullptr;
  root = insert(root, new Pet("cat", 1));
  root = insert(root, new Pet("dog", 2));
  root = insert(root, new Pet("fish", 3));

  root = deleteNode(root, "dog");

  if (search(root, "dog") != nullptr) {
    std::cout << "\n*** TEST6 [Expected [nullptr] but got [" << search(root, "dog") << "]]\n ***"; 
    return false;
  }

  root = deleteNode(root, "cat");

  if (search(root, "cat") != nullptr) {
    std::cout << "\n*** TEST6 [Expected [nullptr] but got [" << search(root, "cat") << "]]\n ***"; 
    return false;
  }

  root = deleteNode(root, "fish");
  
  if(root != nullptr) {
    std::cout << "\n*** TEST6 [Expected [nullptr] but got [" << root << "]] ***\n";
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}

/** DOCUMENTATION:
 * PRIVATE: @name bool ShelterBST::testDestroyTree()
 * @brief Private function to test destroyTree() method of ShelterBST class.
 * @return Returns a boolean value indicating whether the test has passed or not.
 */
bool ShelterBST::testDestroyTree() { //?7
  TreeNode* root = nullptr;
  root = insert(root, new Pet("D", 3));
  root = insert(root, new Pet("B", 2));
  root = insert(root, new Pet("A", 2));
  root = insert(root, new Pet("C", 2));
  root = insert(root, new Pet("F", 2));
  root = insert(root, new Pet("G", 2));
  root = insert(root, new Pet("E", 2));

  root = destroyTree(root);

  if (root != nullptr) {
    std::cout << "\n*** TEST7 [Expected [nullptr] but got [" << root << "]] ***\n"; 
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}

/** DOCUMENTATION:
 * PRIVATE: @name bool ShelterBST::testNumberOfChildren() 
 * @brief Private function to test numberOfChildren() method of ShelterBST class.
 * @return Returns a boolean value indicating whether the test has passed or not.
 */
bool ShelterBST::testNumberOfChildren() { //?8
  TreeNode* root = nullptr;
  root = insert(root, new Pet("D", 3));
  root = insert(root, new Pet("B", 2));
  root = insert(root, new Pet("A", 2));
  root = insert(root, new Pet("C", 2));
  root = insert(root, new Pet("F", 2));
  root = insert(root, new Pet("G", 2));
  root = insert(root, new Pet("E", 2));
  root = insert(root, new Pet("Z", 2));
  
  int EQnumChildrenOne = 0;
  int EQnumChildrenTwo = 1;
  int EQnumChildrenThree = 2;

  int numChildrenRoot = numberOfChildren(root, "D"); //has 2 children
  if (numChildrenRoot != EQnumChildrenThree) {
    std::cout << "\n*** TEST8 [Expected [" << EQnumChildrenThree << "] but got [" << numChildrenRoot << "]] ***\n";
    return false;
  }

  int numChildrenLeaf = numberOfChildren(root, "C"); //has zero children
  if (numChildrenLeaf != EQnumChildrenOne) {
    std::cout << "\n*** TEST8 [Expected [" << EQnumChildrenOne << "] but got [" << numChildrenLeaf << "]] ***\n";
    return false;
  }

  int numChildrenHanging = numberOfChildren(root, "G"); //has one child
  if (numChildrenHanging != EQnumChildrenTwo) {
    std::cout << "\n*** TEST8 [Expected [" << EQnumChildrenThree << "] but got [" << numChildrenHanging << "]] ***\n";
    return false;
  }
  destroyTree(root);
  return true;
}

/** DOCUMENTATION:
 * PRIVATE: @name bool ShelterBST::testNumberOfNodes() 
 * @brief Private function to test numberOfNodes() method of ShelterBST class.
 * @return Returns a boolean value indicating whether the test has passed or not.
 */
bool ShelterBST::testNumberOfNodes() { //?9
  TreeNode* root = nullptr;

  /** @note the tree is degenerate*/
  root = insert(root, new Pet("A", 1));
  root = insert(root, new Pet("B", 2));
  root = insert(root, new Pet("C", 3));
  root = insert(root, new Pet("D", 4));
  root = insert(root, new Pet("E", 5));
  root = insert(root, new Pet("F", 6));
  root = insert(root, new Pet("G", 7));
  root = insert(root, new Pet("H", 8));
  root = insert(root, new Pet("I", 9));
  root = insert(root, new Pet("J", 10));
  root = insert(root, new Pet("K", 11));
  root = insert(root, new Pet("L", 12));
  root = insert(root, new Pet("M", 13));
  root = insert(root, new Pet("N", 14));
  root = insert(root, new Pet("O", 15));
  root = insert(root, new Pet("P", 16));
  root = insert(root, new Pet("R", 17));
  root = insert(root, new Pet("S", 18));
  root = insert(root, new Pet("T", 19));
  root = insert(root, new Pet("U", 20));
  root = insert(root, new Pet("V", 21));
  root = insert(root, new Pet("Z", 22));
  root = insert(root, new Pet("Q", 23));

  int EQnumNodes = 23;
  int numNodes = numberOfNodes(root);

  if (numNodes != EQnumNodes) {
    std::cout << "\n*** TEST9 [Expected [" << EQnumNodes << "] but got [" << numNodes << "]] ***\n";
    return false;
  }
  destroyTree(root);
  return true;
}

/** DOCUMENTATION:
 * PRIVATE: @name bool ShelterBST::testNumberOfInternalNodes()
 * @brief Private function to test numberOfInternalNodes() method of ShelterBST class.
 * @return Returns a boolean value indicating whether the test has passed or not.
 */
bool ShelterBST::testNumberOfInternalNodes() { //?10
  TreeNode* root = nullptr;
  root = insert(root, new Pet("F", 1));
  root = insert(root, new Pet("C", 2));
  root = insert(root, new Pet("J", 3));
  root = insert(root, new Pet("B", 4));
  root = insert(root, new Pet("D", 5));
  root = insert(root, new Pet("G", 6));
  root = insert(root, new Pet("Z", 7));

  int EQinternalNodes =  3;
  int internalNodes = numberOfInternalNodes(root);

  if(EQinternalNodes != internalNodes) {
    std::cout << "\n*** TEST10 [Expected [" << EQinternalNodes << "] but got [" << internalNodes << "]] ***\n";
    return false;
  }

  destroyTree(root);
  return true;
}

/** DOCUMENTATION:
 * PRIVATE: @name bool ShelterBST::testHeight() 
 * @brief Private function to test findHeight() method of ShelterBST class.
 * @return Returns a boolean value indicating whether the test has passed or not. 
 */
bool ShelterBST::testHeight() { //?11
  TreeNode* root = nullptr;

  /** @note the tree is degenarate/sparse*/

  root = insert(root, new Pet("A", 1));
  root = insert(root, new Pet("B", 2));
  root = insert(root, new Pet("C", 3));
  root = insert(root, new Pet("D", 4));
  root = insert(root, new Pet("E", 5));
  root = insert(root, new Pet("F", 6));
  root = insert(root, new Pet("G", 7));
  root = insert(root, new Pet("H", 8));
  root = insert(root, new Pet("I", 9));
  root = insert(root, new Pet("J", 10));
  root = insert(root, new Pet("K", 11));
  root = insert(root, new Pet("L", 12));
  root = insert(root, new Pet("M", 13));
  root = insert(root, new Pet("N", 14));
  root = insert(root, new Pet("O", 15));
  root = insert(root, new Pet("P", 16));
  root = insert(root, new Pet("Q", 17));
  root = insert(root, new Pet("R", 18));
  root = insert(root, new Pet("S", 19));
  root = insert(root, new Pet("T", 20));
  root = insert(root, new Pet("U", 21));
  root = insert(root, new Pet("V", 22));
  root = insert(root, new Pet("W", 23));
  root = insert(root, new Pet("X", 24));
  root = insert(root, new Pet("Y", 25));
  root = insert(root, new Pet("Z", 26));

  int EQheight = 26;
  int height = findHeight(root);

  if(EQheight != height) {
    std::cout << "\n*** TEST11 [Expected [" << EQheight << "] but got [" << height << "]] *** \n";
    return false;
  }
  destroyTree(root);
  return true;  
}

/** DOCUMENTATION:
 * PRIVATE: @name bool ShelterBST::testBalance() 
 * @brief Private function to test isBalanced() method of ShelterBST class.
 * @return Returns a boolean value indicating whether the test has passed or not.
 */
bool ShelterBST::testBalance() { //?12
  TreeNode* root = nullptr;
  root = insert(root, new Pet("F", 1));
  root = insert(root, new Pet("C", 2));
  root = insert(root, new Pet("J", 3));
  root = insert(root, new Pet("B", 4));
  root = insert(root, new Pet("D", 5));
  root = insert(root, new Pet("G", 6));
  root = insert(root, new Pet("Z", 7));

  bool EQbalance = true;
  bool balance = isBalanced(root);

  if(EQbalance != balance) {
    /** @note boolalpha -> prints true and flase isnstead of 1 and 0*/
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << "\n *** TEST12 [Expected [" << EQbalance << "] but got [" << balance << "]] ***\n";
    return false;
  }
  destroyTree(root);
  return true;    
}

/** DOCUMENTATION:
 * PRIVATE: @name bool ShelterBST::testNodesAtLevel()
 * @brief Private function to test nodesAtLevel() method of ShelterBST class.
 * @return Returns a boolean value indicating whether the test has passed or not.
 */
bool ShelterBST::testNodesAtLevel() { //?13
  TreeNode* root = nullptr;
  root = insert(root, new Pet("F", 1));
  root = insert(root, new Pet("C", 2));
  root = insert(root, new Pet("J", 3));
  root = insert(root, new Pet("B", 4));
  root = insert(root, new Pet("D", 5));
  root = insert(root, new Pet("G", 6));
  root = insert(root, new Pet("R", 13));
  root = insert(root, new Pet("Z", 7));

  int EQnodesAtLevelZero = 1; //root
  int EQnodesAtLevelOne = 2; //root children
  int EQnodesAtLevelTwo = 4; //full -> perfect tree, splits to two more
  int EQnodesAtLevelThree = 1; //Z

  int nodesAtLevelZero = numberOfNodesAtLevel(root, 0);
  int nodesAtLevelOne = numberOfNodesAtLevel(root, 1);
  int nodesAtLevelTwo = numberOfNodesAtLevel(root, 2);
  int nodesAtLevelThree = numberOfNodesAtLevel(root, 3);

  if(EQnodesAtLevelZero != nodesAtLevelZero) {
    std::cout << "\n*** TEST13[A] [Expected [" << EQnodesAtLevelZero << "] but got [" << nodesAtLevelZero << "]] ***\n";
    return false;
  }

  if(EQnodesAtLevelOne != nodesAtLevelOne) {
    std::cout << "\n*** TEST13[B] [Expected [" << EQnodesAtLevelOne << "] but got [" << nodesAtLevelOne << "]] ***\n";
    return false;
  }

  if(EQnodesAtLevelTwo != nodesAtLevelTwo) {
    std::cout << "\n*** TEST13[C] [Expected [" << EQnodesAtLevelTwo << "] but got [" << nodesAtLevelTwo << "]] ***\n";
    return false;
  }

  if(EQnodesAtLevelThree != nodesAtLevelThree) {
    std::cout << "\n*** TEST13[D] [Expected [" << EQnodesAtLevelThree << "] but got [" << nodesAtLevelThree << "]] ***\n";
    return false;
  }      

  destroyTree(root);
  return true;   
}

/** DOCUMENTATION:
 * PRIVATE: @name bool ShelterBST::testInOrder()
 * @brief Private function to test inOrder() method of ShelterBST class.
 * @return Returns a boolean value indicating whether the test has passed or not.
 */
bool ShelterBST::testInOrder() { //?14
  TreeNode* root = nullptr;
  root = insert(root, new Pet("F", 1));
  root = insert(root, new Pet("C", 2));
  root = insert(root, new Pet("J", 3));
  root = insert(root, new Pet("B", 4));
  root = insert(root, new Pet("D", 5));
  root = insert(root, new Pet("G", 6));
  root = insert(root, new Pet("Z", 7));

  std::vector<std::string> names;
  findPredecessorHelper(root, names);

  std::vector<std::string> EQ = {"B", "C", "D", "F", "G", "J", "Z"};

  if(names == EQ) { // == operator defined int the vector class (no need to iterate)
    return true;
  } else {
    for(auto i = 0; i < (int)names.size(); i++) {
      if(names[i] != EQ[i]) {
        std::cout << "\n*** TEST14 [Expected [" << EQ[i] << "] but got [" << names[i] << "]] ***\n";
        return false;
      }
    }
  }
  destroyTree(root);
  return true;
}

/** DOCUMENTATION:
 * PRIVATE: @name bool ShelterBST::testPreOrder()
 * @brief Private function to test preOrder() method of ShelterBST class.
 * @return Returns a boolean value indicating whether the test has passed or not.
 */
bool ShelterBST::testPreOrder() { //?15
  TreeNode* root = nullptr;
  root = insert(root, new Pet("F", 1));
  root = insert(root, new Pet("C", 2));
  root = insert(root, new Pet("J", 3));
  root = insert(root, new Pet("B", 4));
  root = insert(root, new Pet("D", 5));
  root = insert(root, new Pet("G", 6));
  root = insert(root, new Pet("Z", 7));
  
  std::vector<std::string> names;
  preOrderHelper(root, names);

  std::vector<std::string> EQ = {"B", "D", "C", "G", "Z", "J", "F"};

  if(names == EQ) { // == operator defined int the vector class (no need to iterate)
    return true;
  } else {
    for(auto i = 0; i < (int)names.size(); i++) {
      if(names[i] != EQ[i]) {
        std::cout << "\n*** TEST14 [Expected [" << EQ[i] << "] but got [" << names[i] << "]] ***\n";
        return false;
      }
    }
  }
  destroyTree(root);
  return true;
}

/** DOCUMENTATION:
 * PRIVATE: @name bool ShelterBST::testPostOrder()
 * @brief Private function to test postOrder() method of ShelterBST class.
 * @return Returns a boolean value indicating whether the test has passed or not.
 */
bool ShelterBST::testPostOrder() { //?16
  TreeNode* root = nullptr;
  root = insert(root, new Pet("F", 1));
  root = insert(root, new Pet("C", 2));
  root = insert(root, new Pet("J", 3));
  root = insert(root, new Pet("B", 4));
  root = insert(root, new Pet("D", 5));
  root = insert(root, new Pet("G", 6));
  root = insert(root, new Pet("Z", 7));
  
  std::vector<std::string> names;
  postOrderHelper(root, names); 
  
  std::vector<std::string> EQ = {"F", "C", "B", "D", "J", "G", "Z"}; //Z

  if(names == EQ) { // == operator defined int the vector class (no need to iterate)
    return true;
  } else {
    for(auto i = 0; i < (int)names.size(); i++) {
      if(names[i] != EQ[i]) {
        std::cout << "\n*** TEST16 [Expected [" << EQ[i] << "] but got [" << names[i] << "]] ***\n";
        return false;
      }
    }
  }
  destroyTree(root);
  return true;
}

/** DOCUMENT:
 * PRIVATE: @name std::vector<bool> ShelterBST::runAllTests()
 * @brief Runs all tests on the ShelterBST object and returns a map of the test results.
 * @return An unordered map with the test results. The keys are strings representing the test names,
 * and the values are booleans indicating whether each test passed (true) or failed (false).
 */
std::vector<bool> ShelterBST::runAllTests(std::vector<bool> &testResults) {
  testResults.push_back(testSearch());
  testResults.push_back(testSearchB());
  testResults.push_back(testInsert()); 
  testResults.push_back(testFindParent());
  testResults.push_back(testFindPredecessor());
  testResults.push_back(testDeleteNode());
  testResults.push_back(testDestroyTree());
  testResults.push_back(testNumberOfChildren());
  testResults.push_back(testNumberOfNodes());
  testResults.push_back(testNumberOfInternalNodes());
  testResults.push_back(testHeight());
  testResults.push_back(testBalance()); 
  testResults.push_back(testNodesAtLevel()); 
  testResults.push_back(testInOrder());
  testResults.push_back(testPreOrder()); 
  testResults.push_back(testPostOrder());
  
  return testResults;
}

/** DOCUMENTATION:
 * PUBLIC: @name void ShelterBST::test()
 * @brief Runs tests for all the funcntions
 */
void ShelterBST::test() {
  using std::vector;
  #define PASS true //macro preprocessor directive
  #define FAIL false
  std::string const TEST = "*** TEST ";
  std::string const PASSED = "  PASSED ***";
  std::string const FAILED = "  - FAILED ###";
  std::string const PASSED_2 = " PASSED ***";
  std::string const FAILED_2 = " - FAILED ###";
  long int const PAUSE = 1000000;

  vector<bool> testValues;
  std::cout << "\n\n*** RUNNING ALL TESTS *** ";
  std::cout << std::flush; //flush the buffer or else usleep doesn't work
  usleep(PAUSE);
  runAllTests(testValues);
  std::cout << std::endl << std::endl;
  for(auto i = 0; i < (int)testValues.size(); i++) {
    if(testValues[i] == PASS && i < 9) { /** @bug fail and pass*/
      std::cout << TEST << i+1 << PASSED << std::endl;

    } else if(testValues[i] == FAIL && i < 9) {
      std::cout << TEST << i+1 << FAILED << std::endl;

    } else if(testValues[i] == PASS && i > 9) {
      std::cout << TEST << i+1 << PASSED_2 << std::endl;

    } else if(testValues[i] == FAIL && i > 9) {
      std::cout << TEST << i+1 << FAILED_2 << std::endl;
    }
  }
}
```

**`assignment3.cpp`**

```
/** DOCUMENTATION:
 * @author Jakob Balkovec
 * @file assignment3.cpp [Driver Code]
 * @note Driver code for A3
 * 
 * @brief This assigment focuses on using multiple operations regarding BST like:
 *   - Insertion
 *   - Traversals
 *   - Searching
 *   - Deletion
 * 
 * Those operations were implemented using a ShelterBST class that includes a struct for Pets and
 * A struct for the TreeNodes.  
 */

#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include "ShelterBST.h"
#include <vector>
#include <limits>

#pragma message("[" __FILE__"] " "Last compiled on [" __DATE__ "] at [" __TIME__"]")


/** @name OPID (opeartion ID)
 * @enum for the switch statement
 * @brief Every operation has a numerical value
 */
enum OPID {
           ID_1 = 1,
           ID_2 =2,
           ID_3 = 3,
           ID_4 = 4,
           ID_5 = 5,
           ID_6 = 6,
           ID_7 = 7,
           ID_8 = 8,
           ID_9 = 9,
           ID_10 = 10,
           ID_11 = 11,
           ID_12 = 12,
           ID_13 = 13,
           ID_14 = 14,
           ID_15 = 15,
           ID_16 = 16
};

/** @name printTitle()
 * @brief The function prints the title
 * @remark Handles UI
 * @return void-type
 */
void printTitle() {
  std::cout << "\n\n*** [binary search tree]. *** \n\n";
  std::cout << "[select one of the following]\n\n";
}

/** @name printMenu()
 * @brief The function prints a menu for the user
 * @remark Handles UI
 * @return void-type
 */
void printMenu() {
  std::cout << "\n\n"
            << "[1] [in-order traversal]\n"
            << "[2] [pre-order traversal]\n"
            << "[3] [post-order traversal]\n"
            << "[4] [insert a pet]\n"
            << "[5] [find the predecessor]\n"
            << "[6] [find the parent]\n"
            << "[7] [search for a pet]\n"
            << "[8] [delete a node]\n"
            << "[9] [number of nodes]\n"
            << "[10] [number of internal nodes]\n"
            << "[11] [number of nodes per level]\n"
            << "[12] [get the height]\n"
            << "[13] [BST balance]\n"
            << "[14] [destroy BST]\n"
            << "[15] [quit]\n"
            << "[16] [run-tests]\n";
}

/** @name goodbye()
 * @brief The function prompts the user goodbye
 * @remark Handles UI
 * @return void-type
 */
void goodbye() {
  std::cout << "\n\nGoodbye!\n\n";
}

/** @name getInput()
 * @brief The function prompts the user to enter a number corresponding to the menu
 * @return int choice (0 < choice < 8)
 */
int getInput() {
  int const MIN = 1;
  int const MAX = 17;
  int choice = 0;
  std::cout << "\n[Enter]: ";
  
  while (true) {
    try {
      std::cin >> choice;
      if (std::cin.fail()) { //std::cin.fail() if the input is not an intiger returns true
        /// @link https://cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/2957/
        
        std::cin.clear(); // clear error flags
        std::cin.ignore(10000, '\n'); // ignore up to 10000 characters or until a newline is encountered
        throw std::invalid_argument("[Invalid input]");
      }
      else if (choice < MIN || choice > MAX) {
        throw std::out_of_range("[Input out of range. Please enter an integer between 1 and 16]");
      }
      else {
        return choice;
      }
    }
    catch (const std::exception& error) {
      std::cout << error.what() << std::endl;
      std::cout << "[Re-enter]: ";
    }
  }
}

/** @name getName()
 * @brief Prompts the user to enter a name
 * @param name passed by reference
 * @return std::string name
 */
std::string getName(std::string &name) {
  std::cout << "[Enter Name]: ";
  while (true) {
    try {
      std::cin >> name;
      if (std::cin.fail()) {
        throw std::runtime_error("[Invalid input. Please enter a valid name]");
      }
      return name;
    } catch (const std::runtime_error& e) {
      std::cerr << "Error: " << e.what() << std::endl;
      std::cin.clear();
      std::cin.ignore(10000, '\n');
    }
  }
}

/** @name getAge()
 * @brief Prompts the user to enter an age
 * @param age passed by reference
 * @return int age
 */
int getAge(int &age) {
  std::cout << "\n[Enter Age]: ";
  while (true) {
    try {
      std::cin >> age;
      if (std::cin.fail() || age < 0) {
        throw std::runtime_error("[Invalid input. Please enter a positive integer]");
      }
      return age;
    } catch (const std::runtime_error& e) {
      std::cerr << "Error: " << e.what() << std::endl;
      std::cin.clear();
      std::cin.ignore(10000, '\n');
      std::cout << "\n[Enter Age]: ";
    }
  }
}

/** @name getLevel()
 * @brief Prompts the user to enter a level
 * @param level passed by reference
 * @return int level
 */
int getLevel(int &level) { /** @note should I check for user input here -> ???*/
  std::cout << "\n[Enter Level]: ";
  while (true) {
    try {
      std::cin >> level;
      if (std::cin.fail()) { //std::cin.fail() if the input is not an intiger returns true
        /// @link https://cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/2957/
        
        std::cin.clear(); // clear error flags
        std::cin.ignore(10000, '\n'); // ignore up to 10000 characters or until a newline is encountered
        throw std::invalid_argument("[Invalid input]");
      }else {
        return level;
      }
    }
    catch (const std::exception& error) {
      std::cout << error.what() << std::endl;
      std::cout << "[Re-enter]: ";
    }
  }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

  /** DECLARATIONS: */
  ShelterBST tree;
  std::string name = "";
  int age = 0;
  int level = 0;
  
  /** DECLARATIONS: */
  printTitle();
  while(true) {
    printMenu();
    switch(getInput()) {
    case OPID::ID_1: {
      /** @note in-order*/
      tree.inOrderDisplay();
      break;
    }
      
    case OPID::ID_2: {
      /** @note pre-order*/
      tree.preOrderDisplay();
      break;
    }
      
    case OPID::ID_3: {
      /** @note post-order*/
      tree.postOrderDisplay();
      break;
    }
      
    case OPID::ID_4: {
      /** @note insert a pet*/
      tree.insertPet(getName(name), getAge(age));
      break;
    }
      
    case OPID::ID_5: {
      /** @note find predecessor*/
      tree.findInorderPredecessor(getName(name));
      break;
    }
      
    case OPID::ID_6: {
      /** @note find parent*/
      tree.findParent(getName(name));
      break;
    }
      
    case OPID::ID_7: {
      /** @note search for a pet*/
      tree.searchPet(getName(name));
      break;
    }
      
    case OPID::ID_8: {
      /** @note delte a node*/
      tree.deleteNode(getName(name));
      break;
    }
      
    case OPID::ID_9: {
      /** @note number of nodes in BST*/
      tree.numberOfNodes();
      break;
    }
      
    case OPID::ID_10: {
      /** @note  number of internal nodes*/
      tree.numberOfInternalNodes();
      break;
    }
      
    case OPID::ID_11: {
      /** @note number of nodes @ level*/
      tree.numberOfNodesAtLevel(getLevel(level));
      break;
    }
      
    case OPID::ID_12: {
      /** @note get height*/
      tree.findHeight();
      break;
    }
      
    case OPID::ID_13: {
      /** @note is the BST balanced*/
      tree.isBalanced();
      break;
    }
      
    case OPID::ID_14: {
      /** @note destroy the tree*/
      tree.destroyTree();
      break;
    }
      
    case OPID::ID_15: {
      /** @note quit*/
      tree.destroyTree();
      goodbye();
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
      break;
    }
      
    case OPID::ID_16: {
      /** @note run tests*/
      tree.test();
      break;
    }
      
    default: {
      /** @note do nothing...*/
    }
    }
  }
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

**`MakeFile`**

```
CC=g++
CFLAGS= -O3 -Wall -Werror -pedantic -std=c++11

SRCS=ShelterBST.cpp assignment3.cpp
OBJS=$(subst .cpp,.o,$(SRCS))

all: prog

prog: $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(OBJS) -o prog

%.o: %.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

clean:
    rm -f $(OBJS) prog
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Things you would not do in real code

I know you have been given some restrictions, however in code you write outside of a course you would not have these restrictions and you would do things differently. I just want to point that out for readers:

- C++11 is quite old and nowadays you'd aim for C++20, unless you can't because of backwards compatibility reasons.
- You would definitely use templates to make your code more generic. In particular, you could create a `template<typename T> class BST`, have a separate `class Pet`, and then you can `typedef BST<Pet> ShelterBST`.
- Of course if you just want a container for pets sorted on name, and don't care too much about the underlying datastructure, you'd use a standard container like `std::set` or `std::map`.

That said, you will definitely learn some useful things about C++ from the given assignment.

## Documentation format

I see you have comments in your code that look remarkably similar to [Doxygen style comments](https://www.doxygen.nl/manual/docblocks.html), but not quite. It would be great if you follow the Doyxgen format exactly; this way the Doxygen tools can generate PDF and HTML versions of the documentation, check that you have documented everything, and some code editors even understand Doxygen as well and will be able to display it when you hover over function and class names.

## Separate concerns

Your code does not follow the [separation of concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) design principle. The `ShelterBST` class does too many things: it contains the logic of managing the BST, it has unit tests built-in, and it can interact with the user, printing directly to `std::cout`.

Having a function `void insertPet(std::string name, int age)` is fine, but `void searchPet(std::string name)` is bad, because it doesn't return anything to the caller, it just prints to `std::cout`. That means you can't do anything other than printing whether that pet is in the database or not. What if you want to know its age? What if there was more data stored in `class Pet`? Ideally, a function like `searchPet()` would return a pointer to the `Pet` that was found, or `nullptr` in case the pet was not found. The caller can then decide what to do with the result, which greatly increases the flexibility of that function.

So how to do this for things like `inOrderDisplay()`? You want to separate the act of traversing the BST in order from displaying the items. You can do this in C++ by creating a function `inOrderVisit()` that takes a [`std::function`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) as a parameter, so the caller can pass a function to `inOrderVisit()`, and the latter can call it for every item it visits:

```
void inOrderVisit(std::function<void(Pet*)>);
```

The caller could then do:

```
ShelterBST shelter;
…
auto printPet = [](Pet* pet) {
    std::cout << "Name: [" << pet->name << "]   Age: [" << pet->age << "]\n";
};
shelter.inOrderVisit(printPet);
```

Note that `printPet` is a lambda in this example (still C++11), but you could just make it a regular function as well. You want to write a test for pre-order traversal? There is no more need for a `preOrderHelper()`; just pass `preOrderVisit()` a different function:

```
ShelterBST shelter;
shelter.addPet("F", 1");
shelter.addPet("C", 2");
…
std::vector<std::string> names;
shelter.preOrderVisit([&](Pet *pet){ names.push_back(pet->name); });
```

A more advanced option would be to add iterators, so you can use a range-`for` loop. It would allow you to write code like this:

```
ShelterBST shelter;
…
for (Pet* pet: shelter.preOrder()) {
    std::cout << "Name: [" << pet->name << "]   Age: [" << pet->age << "]\n";
}
```

## Unit tests

For the unit tests, ideally you would only need to use public functions to test the functionality of your class. With the above changes you can already test if the search functionality and traversal work without needing access to private functions. However, if you really want to be able to access private members in the tests, then one way is to make a test class or function and declare that as a `friend` inside `ShelterBST`. That way, the test class has access to the private internals of any `ShelterBST` object.

There are [lots of unit test libraries for C++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_unit_testing_frameworks#C++). You would typically use one of those that fits your needs. The more powerful libraries make both writing tests and running them easier.

## What about the move constructor?

I see you wrote a copy constructor and copy assignment operator, but what about the move constructor and move assignment operator? It would be nice to implement those as well.

## Use `'\n'` instead of `std::endl`

[Prefer to use `'\n'` instead of `std::endl`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/213907/stdendl-vs-n); the latter is equivalent to the former, but also forces the output to be flushed, which is usually unnecessary and negatively impacts performance.

## Avoid obsolete and non-standard functions

`usleep()` is neither C nor C++. It's a POSIX function which has been deprecated in 2001. If you are writing in C, then use the POSIX `nanosleep()` or `clock_nanosleep()` functions. However, in C++11 the standard way to sleep is to use [`std::this_thread::sleep_for()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_for).

Comment: Thanks, for the feedback. This is freshman college level so I have 0 to no experience with how they do stuff in the industry (doxygen comments), I just wanted things to be neat. This assignment took me at least a week and I am aware of some flaws. In this assignment we followed the rule of 3 rather than the rule of 5 since we haven't covered move semantics at that point, hence no move constructor. I am rewriting this program in C# since OOP next year is in C# and I figured a little practice beforehand wouldn't hurt, I will take your remarks into consideration. Thanks again!

Comment: The callback should really accept a reference instead of a pointer.